# Debugging state machine of spring webflow java application

Tags: spring-webflow

We have a spring webflow 2.3 java application. Is it possible to log/print the various decision states or action states when a request comes in? I took a quick look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/ but didn't find the loggers/jvm command line arguments to be turned on for printing the flow. Thank you.

Comment: it depends on what logging framework you are using. log4j, slf4j, logback etc.

Comment: We did make a simple custom `ExecutionListener` to do this. https://dougbreaux.github.io/2018/07/13/spring-webflow-progress-logging.html